# Autohotkey - 3 keypresses?

Tags: autohotkey

Okay, quick question. I have a script, that runs when `right mouse is pressed + left ctrl is pressed`.

How would I extend this script, so that when `left ctrl + w + right mouse` are pressed, a different script would execute, but not the first one.

So, if I press `LCtrl + w + RButton`, one thing executes, and If I press `LCtrl + RButton`, another thing executes?

I hope this is not too confusing..

Example of what I tried...

```
~LCtrl & ~RButton:: ; do something

#if GetKeyState("RButton","LCtrl") && GetKeyState("RButton","LCtrl") 
    ~w::
        ; do something
    return
#if
```

The problem is, that when I try to do left ctrl + right button + w, first script also executes..

Answer (score 1):

Standard syntax for this is

```
#if getkeystate("w", "P") ; # this "#if" is only for hotkey definitions conditions, not to be confused with "if"
LCtrl & RButton::
     ; do this
return
#if ; end of hotkey conditions
LCtrl & RButton:: ; w is not pressed
    ; do that
return
```

This question exists multiple times already.

Answer (score 0):

Triple combos are hard to work with. Best I could come up with is:

Method 1:

```
~LCtrl & ~RButton up::
    Input, key, L1 T0.5
    if (key == "w")
        MsgBox % "You pressed LCtrl & Rbutton & W"
    else 
        MsgBox % "You just pressed LCtrl & RButton"     
return
```

Method 2:

```
~LCtrl & ~RButton::
    While (A_TimeSinceThisHotkey < 500) {
        If (GetKeyState("w", "P")) {
            MsgBox % "You pressed LCtrl & RButton & W"
            return
        }
    }
    MsgBox % "You Pressed LCtrl & RButton"
return
```